# Query for Foreign Key string ID without fetching the actual entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

Given the model below, when fetching an entity from the `myentity` table with JPA, is there a way to prevent the secondary fetch that would get the entity from the `anotherentity` table, but would provide us with the `externalPk` String value (which is used as a Foreign Key) itself?

As much as I understand that due to the declared types in Java it wouldn't specifically be possible, I do wonder if there's way to access that information without the extra fetch considering it ***is*** indeed right there in that `myentity` table as an actual `varchar` column.

If it can help, we use EclipseLink as our JPA provider.

#### Current model

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@IdClass(MyIdClass.class)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String foo;

    @Id
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String bar;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_foreign_key", referencedColumnName = "external_pk")
    private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
}
```

```java
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class MyIdClass implements Serializable {

    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "anotherentity")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AnotherEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "external_pk", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String externalPk;

    @Column
    private String something;
}
```

Comment: No you can't. But you could define anotherEntity LAZY and then add an extra attribute with just the foreign key

Answer (score 1):

If the oneToOne relation is not optional, you can append the anotation with `optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY` like such:

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "my_foreign_key", referencedColumnName = "external_pk")
private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;
```

You'll then be able to access its key with `myEntity.getAnotherEntity().getKey()` without loading the relation.
[Here's a POC *using hibernate*](https://github.com/lookslikeitsnot/stackoverflow-69847952)

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to review what you have linked. I thought that: **1)** Hibernate didn't care about `FetchType.LAZY` when it came to `*ToOne` relationships and went ahead about loading it anyways. **2)** in case the entity wasn't loaded eagerly yet, accessing it through the getter is precisely what would actually trigger the fetch (`myEntity.getAnotherEntity()`).

Comment: 1) Hibernate has to know whether it should initialize anotherEntity with null or a proxy class. By telling it `optional=false`, it assumes it's not null and doesn't need to eagerly fetch the association (`fetch = FetchType.LAZY` is still required because EAGER is the default).

Comment: 2) Is very counterintuitive, but check the tests in the repo, you can see in the logs that anotherEntity is never fetched. You can also see that myEntity.getAnotherEntity().getSomething() will throw a LazyInitializarionException because AnotherEntity was not fetched.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access the my_foreign_key foreign key value without having to call MyEntity.getAnotherEntity().getId() and perform a full fetch of anotherEntity, you should probably map it as a read-only basic mapping within the MyEntity instance:

```
public class MyEntity {
...
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String bar;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "my_foreign_key", referencedColumnName = "external_pk")
    private AnotherEntity anotherEntity;

    @Column(name = "my_foreign_key",updatable = false, insertable=false)
    private String myForeignKey;
}
```

As an added benefit, while EclipseLink is pretty good about it on this type of mapping, it can be used in queries to prevent inadvertently forcing a table join unnecessarily. Draw backs though are that you must set this value from the relationship yourself to keep the value in synch with the relationship value - @MapsId might work, but it is meant for relationships involved in ID mappings, so might not be portable.

Comment: If I was to opt for a `read-only` column, then I would not be able to change the `OneToOne` relationship to point to a new entity, right?

Comment: The Column definition being read-only does not affect the OneToOne mapping. It just means that changes made to this string don't get persisted in that column. Changes made to the relationship will show up in this string when it is loaded from the DB, and it would be up to the app to keep the two in synch while it is in memory if you change one.